# I dont like this error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: deep-learning

I'm trying to split text to file using cv2 and it pops up an error like this.

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ttbyx0jz\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Code:

```
import cv2
for i in range(1000):
    img = cv2.imread('original/%s.png' %i)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    for j in range(5):
        crop_img = gray[0:50, 8+j*26:8+(j+1)*26]
        cv2.imwrite("splited/%s_%s.png"%(i, j), crop_img)
    print(i)
```

[image: it looks ok]

I've checked path of the images

Comment: I don't like it either.

Comment: Start debugging, which is the initial value of i? This will tell you why you get an error.